# Change pin for Wake-from-hold

Tags: raspbian, gpio, boot

There is this not-so-well-documented feature about shortening Pin 5 (GPIO3) to GND for booting a halted PI (see e.g. [here](http://elinux.org/RPI_safe_mode#Wake_from_Halt.5B1.5D)) which is called `wake-from-hold`.

As it is possible to change almost everything about Pins being high/low or have a certain function with `dt-blob.bin` and `dtoverlays` (I use them both for other purposes) I can't find any documentation about changing that `wake-from-hold`-pin to another pin than GPIO3.

Background: I use `dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown` on GPIO34 and would wish to combine that with the `wake-from-hold`-functionality on the same GPIO.

My main ressources so far:

- [List of dtoverlays](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/overlays/README), but no overlay with "wake" or "boot" functionality
- [List of dt-blob options](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/extra/dt-blob.dts), but again no `pin_defines`-option for my concerns
- I'm aware of the RUN pin (see [datasheet section "8 Booting"](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/RPI-CM-DATASHEET-V1_0.pdf)), which will be my "workaround" but from board layout perspective GPIO34 with GPIO3-functionality would be a much smarter choice.

Do you have any hints on this?

Specs:

- Raspbian Jessie, 4.9.40-v7+ #1022 SMP Sun Jul 30 11:16:10 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
- Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3 with custom board